# Where are stored the crontab commands for a particular user?

Tags: fedora, cron

I installed a new system (Fedora 13) on a new disk.

I have the data of my old system (Fedora 11) on other disk.

I've mount all old partitions to reconfigure the new system like was the old. I have access to my old `/home`, `/etc`, `/usr`...

I would like to know what was in the crontab of my old user. I look in my old `/etc/cron*` and didn't find what I was looking for.

Where are stored the crontab commands for a particular user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the cron daemon you are using, but chances are good that you'll find the user crontabs in `/var/spool/cron`.

Comment: NB these files must never be edited directly

Answer (score 0):

As joschi says /var/spool/cron/ is the place a user's crontab is stored. I.e. where their crontab is located if they run `crontab -e`.

However cronjobs can be set up via other locations and can be run as any given user from those locations, so to be thourough you need to check these other places too.

Other places where cron jobs might be found on a fedora host include:

- `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.d`

The following places are generally places only root cronjobs go, but a root cronjob can su in it's execution, so you might need to check these to, if you don't find what you are looking for elsewhere:

- `/etc/cron.hourly`
- `/etc/cron.daily`
- `/etc/cron.weekly`
- `/etc/cron.monthly`

I *think* that is all of them.